# IIS, Application Pools and Event Logs

Tags: iis-6, windows-event-log, iis

Running IIS 6 on a handful of Windows 2003 Web Ed. servers. Each has some App Pools configured with "Idle Timeout" of x minutes. No recycling, just the idle timeout from the Properties Performance tab.

[image: App Pool idle timeout settings example]

I'd like to see when these guys shutdown from idle in the Event Viewer logs. So far haven't managed to make that happen. I know they're shutting down based on the reduction of w3p.exe processes in the evening and the fact that each day starts with those processes using less memory than at the end of the prev. day.

**What I've Done So Far**

I started at the TechNet article [Logging Worker Process Recycling Events in IIS 6.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756146%28WS.10%29.aspx). For each App Pool I ran the following:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/AppPoolName/EventName true
```

For EventName I used both AppPoolRecycleTime and AppPoolRecycleSchedule.

Next I found the [How to modify Application Pool Recycling events in IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332088) support article. For each App Pool I ran the following:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs Set w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/LogEventOnRecycle 255
```

Still no luck. I suspect in either case I'm not finding the right metabase property to set on or enable.

Does anyone know what I should enable to get logging for App Pool Idle timeouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awww snap. I just found this nugget:

> **Important** The metabase property
>   **IdleTimeout** does not have an
>   associated LogEventOnRecycle property
>   flag. Therefore, when an application
>   pool is shut down because the
>   IdleTimeout value is reached, an Event
>   log entry will not be logged.

at [How to modify Application Pool Recycling events in IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332088) right below the data table. I missed it the first time around.

Apparently what I want to log can't be done.